# Make Poedit work with ES6 template strings?

Tags: ecmascript-6, gettext, poedit

I am using Poedit's "Update from code" function to extract strings from my javascript code.
The issue is that I use ES6 template strings in my code, like so:

```
const myVariable = 5;
const myString = `My variable value is: ${variable}`
```

This causes the following error to appear when I extract the string for translation:

```
warning: RegExp literal terminated too early
```

Some research told me that this is due to a bug with gettext.

Is there a way for me to still use Poedit with template strings or should I give up on the software?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. It turns out that the error was not caused by the template literals, but by the usage of JSX.

The app is a React app and writing something like

```
function MyComponent() {
    return <Comp></Comp>
}
```

Will trigger the warning, while this won't:

```
function MyComponent() {
    return (<Comp></Comp>)
}
```

In general, using JSX anywhere in my code without surrounding it with parenthesis seems to cause the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't give up on Poedit, which isn't even the culprit — GNU gettext is. What you *should* do is to always make sure you're using the latest version of any software you encounter any issues in; chances are your issue was already fixed since you installed your version.

GNU gettext [introduced support for template literals in version 0.20](https://savannah.gnu.org/forum/forum.php?forum_id=9430). Poedit updated its bundled copy of GNU gettext to 0.20 [in version 2.2.4 in September 2019](https://github.com/vslavik/poedit/releases/tag/v2.2.4-oss).

EDIT:
Here's a demonstration that current gettext works with the minimal sensible (i.e. with *something* to extract) code based on your snippet:

```
$ cat test.js
const myVariable = 5;
const myString = `My variable value is: ${variable}`
_('translatable string');

$ xgettext -o- test.js
# SOME DESCRIPTIVE TITLE.
# Copyright (C) YEAR THE PACKAGE'S COPYRIGHT HOLDER
# This file is distributed under the same license as the PACKAGE package.
# FIRST AUTHOR <EMAIL@ADDRESS>, YEAR.
#
#, fuzzy
msgid ""
msgstr ""
"Project-Id-Version: PACKAGE VERSION\n"
"Report-Msgid-Bugs-To: \n"
"POT-Creation-Date: 2020-03-01 10:44+0100\n"
"PO-Revision-Date: YEAR-MO-DA HO:MI+ZONE\n"
"Last-Translator: FULL NAME <EMAIL@ADDRESS>\n"
"Language-Team: LANGUAGE <LL@li.org>\n"
"Language: \n"
"MIME-Version: 1.0\n"
"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=CHARSET\n"
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n"

#: test.js:3
msgid "translatable string"
msgstr ""

$
```

Comment: That is indeed the first thing I did. The issue happens with the latest version of Poedit (2.3). I also have gettext version 0.20.1.

Comment: @RyanPergent I don't know what to tell you except what should be obvious second nature to developers like you: http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/bugs.html ; perhaps reconsider your assumption (unverifiable with just some two out-of-context lines) that your issues have anything to do with template literals.